# How to make a virtual function accept a data type defined only in derived classes?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a C++ class with two virtual functions that use an undefined `State` struct either as the return/parameter type. My problem is that the `State` structs are only defined in the derived classes and the base class knows nothing about it.

```cpp
class Base {
    // Error: Identifier 'State' is undefined
    virtual void serialize(State& last_state) = 0;
    virtual State& getCurrentState() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    struct State { // Every derived class has different State fields
        int32_t x = 0;
        int32_t y = 0;
    } current_state;
    void serialize(State& last_state) override;
    State& getCurrentState() override;
}
```

Virtual data members aren't a thing, so I'm assuming I just can't define a struct twice. I've also thought that maybe I could create an empty base struct and have every derived classes' State inherit from it, but that doesn't seem like a very clean solution.

Some context for what I'm trying to do in case there's a completely different way this problem could be solved:

I have a map of objects inheriting from Base (`std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>`). I sometimes loop over the map and want to call `serialize()` and `getCurrentState()` for each object.
I don't know which derived object I'm accessing, so I can't just cast the base pointer to the derived one. I can't just call a derived classes' members through the base pointer, so what do I do?

Comment: Is `getCurrentState` called for something other than serialization?  Can you change `seriialize` to not take any parameters, so that each derived class will serialize its own state?  Does it make sense for an object to seriialize itself with a different state?

Comment: How would you intend to use the `State` returned by `getCurrentState` if you have no idea what members it has?

Comment: I pass on the state returned from `getCurrentState` to an overloaded function. As for `serialize`, I could probably create a separate version of the function that doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: And how does that overloaded function know what members the `State` has? The only way to know it in your (hypothetical) approach is to know the exact type of the "Owner"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Virtual data members aren't a thing, so I'm assuming I just can't define a struct twice. I've also thought that maybe I could create an empty base struct and have every derived classes' State inherit from it, but that doesn't seem like a very clean solution.

That is indeed what you should do. I think it is cleaner, when you declare the base state as a protected class in `Base`, so

```cpp
class Base {
protected:
    struct State{};
public:
    virtual void serialize(State& last_state) = 0;
    virtual State& getCurrentState() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    struct State : Base::State { // Every derived class has different State fields
        int32_t x = 0;
        int32_t y = 0;
    } current_state;
    void serialize(Base::State& last_state) override; // Note that the Base:: is important, otherwise the function does not override
    State& getCurrentState() override; // You can add Base:: to the return type but you don't have to.
};
```

Comment: *"you cannot inherit private functions"* - you can override private `virtual` functions